# How to send data from Adapter to ViewModel to Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, adapter

My structure is like this, in the `Fragment` I call the `ViewModel` which instantiate the `Adapter`

For each item of my `RecyclerView`, I have a button which I listen

```
binding.addItem.setOnClickListener(onAddItemClicked(product))

private fun onAddToQuoteClicked(product: Product): View.OnClickListener {
    return View.OnClickListener {
        // TODO add item
    }
}
```

I don't know how to send this item data to the fragment, is there a way to do that?

Should I use interface between `Adapter` and `ViewModel` and between `ViewModel` and `Fragment` ?

Or Can I use `RxEvent` & `RxBus` ?

Comment: can you please elaborate? I guess you have to add some logic, and you are adding the listener in the adapter. What do you mean by saying "send the data to the fragment"? What should the fragment do with the data?

Comment: First, the Adapter should be instantiated in the Fragment and the onClickListener should be implemented there, too. Then you don't need to send anything from RecyclerView to Fragment.
Later, you might want to have a public method in the RecyclerView which you call it from Fragment when the item is clicked.

Comment: I mean by "send data to the fragment", I need clicked Item to send to the main activity as result (clicked item) from Fragment

Comment: I don't instantiate the adapter in the fragment but in the ViewModel, I am using MVVM architecture, and I don't know if it is the right way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First for navigation between ViewModel and Fragment -

- you can use RxJava *PublishSubject* make it public and subscribe to it in your Fragment which can use public methods of ViewModel.
- or you can use an interface, better in my opinion as using interface you are using simpler logic, much less errors in that case, and also it is more clean code as you can name methods in interface as you want - easier to read.

Second for communication between Adapter and Fragment - you can use same strategy as described above. In that case I recommend to use RxJava, as usually you would just need to handle one or few click listeners (so it is for example for observable which emits some data object).
  *If you need some code examples text me in comments*.

**UPDATE** - it is better practice to create your Adapter instance in View, as I assume you are using MVVM design pattern (where all UI related code must be located in View component).

**Example Fragment - Adapter communication Rx - PublishSubject**
In your **Adapter**

```
     private val publisher = PublishSubject.create<Product>()
fun getObservableProductItem(): Observable<Product> = publisher.hide()

binding.addItem.setOnClickListener(onAddItemClicked(product))
private fun onAddToQuoteClicked(product: Product): View.OnClickListener {
    return View.OnClickListener {
        publisherRideItem.onNext(items[adapterPosition])
    }
}

override fun onDetachedFromRecyclerView(recyclerView: RecyclerView) {
    publisherRideItem.onComplete()
}
```

And in your **Fragment**

```
 compositeDisposable.add(adapter.getObservableProductItem().subscribe {
            //TODO do whatever you want with it
        })   

  override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    compositeDisposable.clear()
}
```

Comment: Thanks of your response, yes I need an example to communicate between the adapter and Fragment

Comment: you advise me to use **RxJava EventBus** to communicate between Adapter and Fragment

Comment: He advised you that just using an interface is better than introducing a PublishSubject for this

Comment: In case of communication between ViewModel and Fragment it is better to use interface, but between Adapter and Fragment (if you have only 1 or 2 click listeners to handle, I prefer to user RxJava).

Comment: @GhizlaneLotfi if this answer solves your questions, up vote and accept it, otherwise ask more questions I will try to help you.

Answer (score -1):

RxJava PublishSubject is the best option, I would prefer it and it is very easy.

I tried with recyclerView - Fragment - ViewModel. Some will have listadapter -> recyclerVire -> Fragment -> ViewModel. I have explained that below.

List Adapter

specify your PublishSubject here

```
class myapadter : ListAdapter
{
 object RxBus {
    val itemClickStream: PublishSubject<View> = PublishSubject.create()
}
}
```

ViewHolder

in your viewHolder trigger that PublishSubject.

```
class myViewholder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)
{
            itemView.myButton.setOnClickListener {
               v -> RxBus.itemClickStream.onNext(v) }
}
```

Fragment

subscribe to PublishSubject here in the fragment, this will automatically get notified.

```
myapadter.RxBus.itemClickStream.subscribe(){ v ->
            if (v.id == R.id.myButton) {
              viewModel.callyourfunction()
            }
```

Answer (score -2):

You can directly add item through ViewModel reference and subscribe to RxJava EventBus or LiveData change in your Fragment or Activity

Comment: How can I add directly the item through ViewModel Reference?

Comment: Create function in ViewModel to update Data and call that in.